# How to throttle bandwidth for ipalias in Linux

Tags: linux, traffic-shaping, ip-aliasing

I want to slow the connection between some nodes to a virtual node inside one machine. (different nodes use different ip with ip-alias or with different ports)

In Linux, is it possible to slow the bandwidth for a specific IP in ipalias? Or for a specific port maybe. For testing purpose.

Last time I used [ipfw](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/), but it does not support the latest Ubuntu (since I'm using ubuntu). Also, I do not think that traffic control can be used inside the same machine except if one uses virtual machine.

Thanks